# Firestore Batch Update To A New Document Reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm wondering if it's possible to write a batch function to multiple collections with the same unique id created by Firestore. As the document doesn't exist yet.

The following is what I need;

```
const batch = writeBatch(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE);

const uniqueRef = "SOME UNIQUE REF CREATED BY FIRESTORE"

const supportRef = doc(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, uniqueRef)
const chatRef = doc(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, uniqueRef, "chat", "SOME OTHER UNIQUE REF");

batch.set(supportRef, { data: "" }),
batch.set(chatRef, { otherData: "" })
await batch.commit();
```

My assumption is that this isn't possible as the document reference would have to be created before it can be written to on a batch. But I could be missing something here.

Comment: Please provide a real example of how exactly are you initializing the `uniqueRef`. Is it a string?

Comment: The unique ref is what I want created by Firestore. It is not initialised and is needed to be created by Firestore

Comment: Yup, that should be possible. What happens when you try it? Is there an error message?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.